# Nsdate from string format not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I am trying to convert an string date to a NSDate to make some changes in the format.. but it is always returning nil!

This is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//Mon Jan 30 17:40:12 +0000 2012
[df setDateFormat:@"ccc MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:strData];
```

I have tried this format too:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"];
```

I have tried this table:

http://www.deanoj.co.uk/ios-development/nsdateformatter-formatting-strings-reference/

I have tried these links.. and a lot of others:

[Convert NSString to NSDate with string format "Sun, 08 Jan 2012 13:57:38 +0000"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778256/convert-nsstring-to-nsdate-with-string-format-sun-08-jan-2012-135738-0000)

[NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258266/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-nil)

[How to format Facebook/Twitter dates (from the JSON feed) in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329485/how-to-format-facebook-twitter-dates-from-the-json-feed-in-objective-c)

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't forget to release the allocated `NSLocale`, otherwise it will leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I take your code and modify it to this:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"ccc MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
// [df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
// [df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[df setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"Mon Jan 30 17:40:12 +0000 2012"];
NSLog( @"date is %@", date1);
```

I'm getting:

```
2012-01-30 11:36:38.339 TestApp[32182:f803] date is 2012-01-30 17:40:12 +0000
```

Seems like all you should need to do is comment (or remove) those two lines.

Comment: Yes.. it's true.. I don't know why I did that.. Thanks a lot buddy!